# I want to perform logical operation on values posted from a form in php

Tags: php, html

Here is html...

```
<form name="stream" method="post" action="scripts/validate.php">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="attend" value="yes" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="attend">Yes, I will attend the event in Edo State.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="trad" value="yes" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="trad">Yes, I'm interested in getting the Asoebi.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="house" value="yes" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="house">Yes, I am interested in getting Accommodation.</label>
  </div>

  <button class="btn bg-bur text-white h4 btn-block mt-20" type="submit" name="stream">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the php to process the form data but it keeps displaying the same result, "I want the full registration" even when 1 checkbox is checked or none is checked

```
<?php 
if( isset( $_POST['stream'] ) ) {    
    if ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] == 'yes' ) {
        echo "I want the full registration";
    }
    elseif ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
        echo "I want the Asoebi and I will attend";
    }
    elseif ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
        echo "I am only attending";
    }
    elseif ($_POST['attend'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
        echo "I only want Asoebi";
    }
    elseif ($_POST['attend'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
        echo "You haven't selected anything";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you are using single '=' which is assignment, use == or === for comparison, e.g.: `if ($_POST['attend'] = 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] = 'yes' && $_POST['house'] = 'yes' )` should be: `if ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] == 'yes' )`

Comment: read this for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison

Comment: @lovelace It still gives me errors with the '=='

Comment: Show us how you implemented them.

Comment: Updated the code @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the box, $_POST[the name-not-id] comes back with the value.  Somewhat annoyingly (to me), checkboxes that are unchecked return nothing at all.  So, using the attend as an example:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="attend" value="yes">
```

would return "yes" in $_POST["attend"] when the box is checked, no value in $_POST when the box is unchecked.  So you could use several tests to see if it is checked.  For example:

```
if (!empty($_POST["attend"])) ...
```

or

```
if (isset($_POST["attend"]) && $_POST["attend"] === "yes") ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's why I'm getting the errors @worddragon

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes and I will improve my answer.

Comment: Better answer, I think,  You don't need the id's in this case, and generally want to keep the field names unique.

Comment: I've removed the ids but it still gives me the same **'Undefined index'** errors.

Comment: The problem is not your ID's - its your names and values - you have two fields labelled "rsvp" and none labelled "attend".  Also, you have a value "attend", but you are checking it for being equal to "yes".  You need to make your field names (name=...) unique and align the values with what you are checking for.

Comment: Well, I just tested the code you have posted now and it works for me.  Your if-elseif's don't cover all of the possibilities, so some combinations of checks produce no output).  So, for example, checking no boxes does say "You haven't selected anything", while checking just the housing box gives no output.  What type of errors are you seeing with the code that is posted?

Comment: Here is the error I get **Notice: Undefined index:**

Comment: When I check the 3 boxes, it shows "I want the full registration"

When I check the last 2 boxes, it displays error for the first set of argument for checking all 3 boxes but still displays  the result for checking 2 boxes.

I don't want the errors to show, I only want the results if they match the argument

Comment: It works perfectly now.

used **error_reporting(0);** to hide the errors.

Thanks, unless there's any other recommendation you'd like to make?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work.

```
<?php error_reporting(0); if( isset( $_POST['stream'] ) ) {    
if ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] == 'yes' ) {
    echo "I want the full registration";
}
elseif ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
    echo "I want the Asoebi and I will attend";
}
elseif ($_POST['attend'] == 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
    echo "I am only attending";
}
elseif ($_POST['attend'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] == 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
    echo "I only want Asoebi";
}
elseif ($_POST['attend'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['trad'] !== 'yes' && $_POST['house'] !== 'yes' ) {
    echo "You haven't selected anything";
} }?>
```

Comment: Great!  I think the errors were because when the box is NOT checked, its not present in the $_POST array - if you look at my answer, I used 'empty' or 'isset' in my tests, which are language constructs that don't care whether the index exists, and so don't report errors.  I actually turn on all errors and notices in my own code and get rid if them all so I can see when I have real errors.

Comment: **Warning**. This is _not_ a recommended solution. Instead of hiding errors, you should fix them. If you do as @wordragon suggests in the accepted answer, you wouldn't get any _"undefined index"_. It's easy. Just have `isset($_POST['the-key']) && $_POST['the-key'] == 'yes'` (do this for every field) and you will be set. You could also do `$attend = isset($_POST['attend']) ? $_POST['attend'] : null;` (do this for each input) before your `if`-s. Then you just need to use the variables like `if ($attend == 'yes' .....)` and so on and you won't get any warnings any more.